# Visual Basic loan interest and principal calculator

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get the program to output the principal paid out to and the interest paid 
towards a loan of $5000. No input is take its all been declared already.

```
    Private Sub calButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles calButton.Click
    Dim monthlyPayments As Double
    Dim bloanTotal As Double = 5000
    Dim rate As Double = 0.005
    Dim interest As Double
    Dim toPrincipal As Double
    Dim toInterest As Double
    Dim counter As Integer

    Do
        'calculate the montly payments.
        monthlyPayments =
    Financial.Pmt(0.06 / 12, 12, 5000)
        TextBox1.Text = monthlyPayments.ToString("C2")

        counter = counter + 1        'add one to the counter 
        interest = bloanTotal * rate    'calculate interest rate from payment that will only count as interest
        toInterest = monthlyPayments - interest 'amount of monthly payment going towards interest
        toPrincipal = monthlyPayments - toInterest ' amount of monthly payment going towards principal
        bloanTotal = bloanTotal - toPrincipal 'new balance after deducing principal from begining balance

        Label2.Text = toPrincipal.ToString & "      " &
                      toInterest.ToString &
                      ControlChars.NewLine ' concatinate principal and interest strings and create a new line


        If counter = 12 Then 'exit loop once counter has reached 12 and loan amount has reached zero
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Why is it that the loop does not first generate the right principal and interest? Once i remove the loop and if statement with just the area below counter = counter =1 and above the if statement the calculation is correct.

Comment: So what's it outputting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Monthly payment is correct at 430.33. However, principal and 
interest output is (interest) 23.6588644... and -453.991013030...
. The output should be a row of principal reflecting the amount
principal paid out through out the 12 months and a second row displaying
also the interest paid towards the loan of 5000 through the 12
months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the `Financial.Pmt` function is returning a negative number. Because this is accounting, you are telling the function you have recieved a 5000 loan (positive number) and you will be making payments (negative number). If you do this

`monthlyPayments = Math.Abs(Financial.Pmt(0.06 / 12, 12, 5000))`

then your calculations should work out.